# Ubuntu screen scaling affecting unmodified monitors too

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, wayland

I have 4 monitors, the left one is 4k, while the other 3 are 1080p. The problem I am having is that if I have the 1080p monitors on normal scaling, the 4k monitor is basically unusable because everything is too small, but if i set the 4k monitor to 200%, gnome automatically changes the scaling of the other 3 monitors to 200% too and makes them unusable due to everything being too far zoomed in. If I set the 4k monitor to 1080p everything works fine, but not with scaling.

What can I do here? Is there anything in GNOME Tweaks that can fix this? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Wayland enabled.

Comment: Maybe read your question is there 3 or 4 monitors?

Answer (score 1):

I enabled fractional scaling and that seemed to stop GNOME from auto scaling the other two. Then I kept my 4K at 200% scaling and the other two to 100% scaling using the fractional display setting being enabled. For whatever reason, the fractional display setting must be enabled for it to work for me.